# How do I write a Bash script for a C program that takes 4 numerical inputs?

Tags: bash

I am writing a bash script for a c program, where the program asks for a 4 numerical pin inputs. However, when I wrote the script, the output seems to run in a loop, but it doesn't break where it gets identified as the correct number the program will accept.

```
#!/bin/bash

RANGE=9000
count=${RANDOM:0:4}

while [[ "$count" -le $RANGE ]]
do
    number=$RANDOM
    (( "number %= $RANGE" ))
    echo $number
    if [[ "$count" == "$RANGE" ]]; then
        break
    fi
done
```

When I run it, I can see some numbers in the output that returned as 2 or 3 digits, instead of 4. So in theory, what I want to do is find a random number that is 4 digits that the program will take, but I don't know what is the random number, so essentially it is a brute force, or just me manually guessing the pin number.

Comment: Why are you putting your arithmetic expression in quotes? It's just `(( number %= RANGE ))`; no need for `$`s _or_ quotes.

Comment: Anyhow, if you get a 3 digit number that just means the first digit was 0; if you get a 2-digit number, the _first two_ digits are 0.

Comment: ...btw, it's not clear what you mean by "for a C program" in this context.

Comment: This is a c program that I am given that asks for a numerical input. I did not write the c program myself. Also, when I typed the arithmetic expression in quotes, I'm still a newbie at bash, but I will take that in consideration for future scripts.

Answer (score 0):

If all you need is a random 4-digit number, you can do that with:

```
printf -v number "%04d" $((RANDOM % 10000))
```

The `$RANDOM` gives you a random number `0..32767`, the `% 10000` translates that to the range `0..9999` (not *perfectly* distributed, but should be good enough for most purposes), and the `printf` ensures leading zeros are attached to it (so you'll see `0042` rather than `42`, for example).

---

You can test it with the following script:

```
(( total = 0 ))
(( bad = 0 ))
for i in {1..10000} ; do
    printf -v x "%04d" $((RANDOM % 10000))
    (( total += 1 ))
    [[ "${x}" =~ ^[0-9]{4}$ ]] || { echo Bad ${x}; (( bad += 1 )); }
done
(( good = total - bad ))
echo "Tested: ${total}, bad ${bad}, good ${good}"
```

which *should* give you:

```
Tested: 10000, bad 0, good 10000
```

Comment: Insofar as the OP is trying to make guesses at a number, it probably wouldn't do to not be able to guess combinations where the first digit is 0.

Comment: BTW, consider `printf -v x '%04d' "$x"` instead of the command substitution; makes the code bash-specific, but much faster (and it's already bash-specific anyhow).

Comment: Good points, @Charles, I've bought them on-board with another slight improvement that combines the random generation with the `printf`. I don't think being bash-specific is an issue since the question is *tagged* `bash`.

Comment: Thank you for help, that cleared up some confusion about the scripting. I should've known that was the case with the numbers showing as 2 digits, when I was pretty sure I only asked for a certain range of numbers.